# Random/SplittableRandom error while building quarkus native image with optaplanner

Tags: java, drools, quarkus, optaplanner, graalvm

I encounter this "Random/SplittableRandom" error while building my quarkus optaplanner application in a native image:

`docker run --env LANG=C --rm -v /Users/user1/myapp/target/myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z --name build-native-qOeJv quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:22.0.0-java11 -J-Dsun.nio.ch.maxUpdateArraySize=100 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Dvertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxLogDelegateFactory -J-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -J-Dio.netty.leakDetection.level=DISABLED -J-Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder=3 -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -H:-ParseOnce -J--add-exports=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy\$BySpaceAndTime -H:+JNI -H:+AllowFoldMethods -J-Djava.awt.headless=true -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https -H:+InlineBeforeAnalysis -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -jar myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar`

```
Error: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image heap. Instances created during image generation have cached seed values and don't behave as expected.  To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.Random. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>. Or you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly from your main entry point.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field java.util.Collections.r
Error: No instances of java.io.FilePermission are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.io.FilePermission.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.val of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node@2fa9569c reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]@37a65cb2 reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.table of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@2ade02d0 reached by 
    reading field java.io.FilePermissionCollection.perms of
        constant java.io.FilePermissionCollection@7a8b93fb reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.val of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node@7cdf033 reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]@1a17f87 reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.table of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@3c16c45b reached by 
    reading field java.security.Permissions.permsMap of
        constant java.security.Permissions@51058af3 reached by 
    reading field java.security.ProtectionDomain.permissions of
        constant java.security.ProtectionDomain@14be23e7 reached by 
    scanning method org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(PackageClassLoader.java:138)
Call path from entry point to org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(String, byte[]): 
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(PackageClassLoader.java:138)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.internalDefineClass(PackageClassLoader.java:108)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.fastFindClass(PackageClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.loadClass(PackageClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.loadClass(Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.loadFromKJar(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:86)
    at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.run(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:597)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:194)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)

com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image heap. Instances created during image generation have cached seed values and don't behave as expected.  To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.Random. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>. Or you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly from your main entry point.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field java.util.Collections.r
Error: No instances of java.io.FilePermission are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.io.FilePermission.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.val of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node@2fa9569c reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]@37a65cb2 reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.table of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@2ade02d0 reached by 
    reading field java.io.FilePermissionCollection.perms of
        constant java.io.FilePermissionCollection@7a8b93fb reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.val of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node@7cdf033 reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]@1a17f87 reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.table of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@3c16c45b reached by 
    reading field java.security.Permissions.permsMap of
        constant java.security.Permissions@51058af3 reached by 
    reading field java.security.ProtectionDomain.permissions of
        constant java.security.ProtectionDomain@14be23e7 reached by 
    scanning method org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(PackageClassLoader.java:138)
Call path from entry point to org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(String, byte[]): 
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(PackageClassLoader.java:138)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.internalDefineClass(PackageClassLoader.java:108)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.fastFindClass(PackageClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.loadClass(PackageClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.loadClass(Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.loadFromKJar(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:86)
    at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.run(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:597)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:194)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)

    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:87)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FallbackFeature.reportAsFallback(FallbackFeature.java:233)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:731)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:537)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:494)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:426)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:587)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:126)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:617)
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: Unsupported features in 2 methods
Detailed message:
Error: Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image heap. Instances created during image generation have cached seed values and don't behave as expected.  To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.Random. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>. Or you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly from your main entry point.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field java.util.Collections.r
Error: No instances of java.io.FilePermission are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.io.FilePermission.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.val of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node@2fa9569c reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]@37a65cb2 reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.table of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@2ade02d0 reached by 
    reading field java.io.FilePermissionCollection.perms of
        constant java.io.FilePermissionCollection@7a8b93fb reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.val of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node@7cdf033 reached by 
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]@1a17f87 reached by 
    reading field java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.table of
        constant java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@3c16c45b reached by 
    reading field java.security.Permissions.permsMap of
        constant java.security.Permissions@51058af3 reached by 
    reading field java.security.ProtectionDomain.permissions of
        constant java.security.ProtectionDomain@14be23e7 reached by 
    scanning method org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(PackageClassLoader.java:138)
Call path from entry point to org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(String, byte[]): 
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(PackageClassLoader.java:138)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.internalDefineClass(PackageClassLoader.java:108)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.fastFindClass(PackageClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.loadClass(PackageClassLoader.java:56)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.loadClass(Target_java_lang_ClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.loadFromKJar(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:86)
    at org.drools.ancompiler.KieBaseUpdaterANC.run(KieBaseUpdaterANC.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:597)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:194)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)

    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatures.report(UnsupportedFeatures.java:129)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:728)
    ... 6 more
```

I searched and there is this article [working with randoms native image](https://foivos.zakkak.net/tutorials/working-with-randoms-native-images/) but I still could not figure out what I need to do to resolve this.

Seems like quarkus tries to create an instance of Random or SplittableRandom for a drools class, I am using optaplanner quarkus and I do not use drools rule engine, I use constraint streams.

Does anyone have the same problem while building native image for optaplanner quarkus application? What should I do to overcome this? I tried graalvm 22.0 and 21.3, both have the same problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Could you please share what OptaPlanner version you use? Generally, it's better to use the latest stable version (currently 8.20.0.Final).

Comment: I use optaplanner 8.20.0.Final and the problem is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line tells me that there is a problem on your classpath:

```
Call path from entry point to org.drools.wiring.dynamic.PackageClassLoader.writeClass(String, byte[]):
```

The `drools-wiring-dynamic` module is not designed to work in the native mode, and needs to be replaced by `drools-wiring-static`. In fact, the `optaplanner-quarkus` module does all this work for you.

Are you using `optaplanner-quarkus` instead of `optaplanner-core`? The stack trace tells me you maybe aren't. If you are, I suggest you figure out the source of the `drools-wiring-dynamic` dependency, and remove it.

One other source of problems may be that you are trying to use constraint DRL in native mode. That is not supported and will fail with one exception or another. In native mode, you have three choices for constraints - Constraint Streams, Java Incremental or Java Easy.

Comment: I did find in my pom file I have optaplanner-core and optaplanner-quarkus, so I removed optaplanner-core, now I still have the same Random/SplittableRandom but I am not sure now the error is from drool or anywhere else:

Comment: Error: Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image heap. Instances created during image generation have cached seed values and don't behave as expected.  To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=java.util.Random. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>....
Detailed message:
Trace: Object was reached by 
 reading field java.util.Collections.r

Comment: at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:87)
 at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FallbackFeature.reportAsFallback(FallbackFeature.java:233)
 at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:731)
 at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:537)
 at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:494)
 at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:426)
 at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGenerator..

Comment: Yes I found it's one of my object has a property which is initialized with a "shuffled" call, and shuffled use Random. I removed the "shuffled" call, and its working now. So the take away is, first make sure optaplanner-core is not in the pom, only use optaplanner-quarkus in the pom. And make sure all classes initialization does not call any method like "shuffled" which in turn uses Radom class